# File parsing in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to parse a file in the following format.

```
Case1: 0x5sdf258:648s4df ..;. ABCD hhbdch ; extra text 
Case2: 0xdef58e1:18w4we1 .... HCDC ajdknlmk ;extra text
```

I want to remove the extra text after the semicolon, So I use the following line

```
   $row =~ s/;.*//g;
```

This works in case 2 but fails in case 1. Is there a method in which I can perform my task in both the cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;(?!.*;).*
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/30

Comment: This regex, which should have been explained by its poster, finds a semi-colon, that is not followed by any other semi-colons.  But I fear that it uses an inefficient method to arrive at an answer, using a zero-width negative lookahead assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
$row =~ s/;[^;]*$//g;
```

OR

```
$row =~ s/;[^;\n]*$//g;
```

This would remove the text after the last semicolon (*including semicolon*).

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uS5qR5/2)

- `[^;]*` negated character class which matches any charcater but not of `;` , zero or more times.
- `$` asserts that we are at the end.

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(my $line = <DATA>) {
    $line =~ s/;[^;]*$//g;
    print $line."\n";
}


__DATA__
Case1: 0x5sdf258:648s4df ..;. ABCD hhbdch ; extra text 
Case2: 0xdef58e1:18w4we1 .... HCDC ajdknlmk ;extra text
```

**Output:**

```
Case1: 0x5sdf258:648s4df ..;. ABCD hhbdch 
Case2: 0xdef58e1:18w4we1 .... HCDC ajdknlmk
```

Comment: I don't know the reason but it didn't work for me... Can you provide me an explanation?

Comment: I don't know how it works in this demo. In actual code it still fails. I have already chomped the line.

Comment: Anyways I figured out another method:
$row =~ s/(0x[0-9a-f]+:\s+\w+\s+....\s+.*);.*$/$1/g;
Case1 and Case2 text are not a part of line.